# How can I achieve a dashed or dotted border in WPF?

Tags: wpf, styles, border, listviewitem

I have a `ListViewItem` that I am applying a `Style` to and I would like to put a dotted grey line as the bottom `Border`.

How can I do this in WPF? I can only see solid color brushes.

Comment: Did you check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1630022/dotted-border-on-listboxitem-in-wpf

Comment: No - Thanks for that. You don't know of a _simple_ way do you? It seems like a bit of a hack.

Comment: Related post, and probably the best answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14936002/dotted-border-around-a-button

Answer (score 128, accepted):

This worked great in our application, allowing us to use a real Border and not mess around with Rectangles:

```
<Border BorderThickness="1,0,1,1">
   <Border.BorderBrush>
      <DrawingBrush Viewport="0,0,8,8" ViewportUnits="Absolute" TileMode="Tile">
         <DrawingBrush.Drawing>
            <DrawingGroup>
               <GeometryDrawing Brush="Black">
                  <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                     <GeometryGroup>
                        <RectangleGeometry Rect="0,0,50,50" />
                        <RectangleGeometry Rect="50,50,50,50" />
                     </GeometryGroup>
                  </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
               </GeometryDrawing>
            </DrawingGroup>
         </DrawingBrush.Drawing>
      </DrawingBrush>
   </Border.BorderBrush>

   <TextBlock Text="Content Goes Here!" Margin="5"/>
</Border>
```

Note that the Viewport determines the size of the dashes in the lines. In this case, it generates eight-pixel dashes. Viewport="0,0,4,4" would give you four-pixel dashes.

Comment: how can this be used on other elements which needs the same style.

Comment: You can define a style that includes the DrawingBrush and then apply that style to whatever elements you want.

Comment: The two rectangles are actually aligned in such a way that this pattern works all around the border, horizontal and vertical, left and right. (Better don't try to use it for non-rectangular lines though...)

Comment: Done this way could the dashes offset still be animated?

Comment: unapproved best solution.:)

Comment: It's pretty clever to draw a checkboard and use that as the border, but it only works for a width of 1, and even then it can look fuzzy at times. I've tried to get rid of this with the options here but have not succeeded: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5585082/how-to-turn-off-the-anti-aliasing-in-wpf-shapes

Comment: This is how it works: https://prnt.sc/pWytkHZJt2ea
This is with the border of 50 px (just to see how it fills). This looks to support 1 px border only. Moreover, the rectangle size may be fractional (like 10.3 px), so sometimes the border is filled with something absolutely unexpected.

Answer (score 107):

You can create a dotted or dashes line using a rectangle like in the code below

```
<Rectangle Stroke="#FF000000" Height="1" StrokeThickness="1" StrokeDashArray="4 4"
                                                       SnapsToDevicePixels="True"/>
```

Get started with this and customize  your listview according to your scenario

Comment: Any way to do that with rounded corners?

Comment: @Jordan Use `RadiusX="10" RadiusY="10"`.

Comment: Any way to tilt the dotted lines?

Answer (score 41):

A bit late to the party, but the following solution worked for me. It is slightly simpler/better than both other solutions:

```
<Border BorderThickness="1">
  <Border.BorderBrush>
    <VisualBrush>
      <VisualBrush.Visual>
        <Rectangle StrokeDashArray="4 2" Stroke="Gray" StrokeThickness="1"
                  Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Border}}, Path=ActualWidth}"
                  Height="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Border}}, Path=ActualHeight}"/>
      </VisualBrush.Visual>
    </VisualBrush>
  </Border.BorderBrush>

  <TextBlock Text="Whatever" />
</Border>
```

Comment: Brilliance.  The 1st answer was poor with rounded corners.  This one works excellently.  Just set RadiusX/Y on the Rectangle to the same CornerRadius that's on the Border.

Comment: Should be preferred answer. I prefer this answer as it's the cleanest, shortest and most readable (intuitive) solution.

Comment: ...however! If you use this brush as a `staticresource` or `dynamicresource`, something goes wrong. I assume due to the `Width` and `Height` bindings failing.
The 1st answer *does* work as a reusable resource. Pity. I really like this solution.

Comment: It's lightweight, but it's not symmetrical.

Answer (score 6):

Xaml

```html
<Grid>
<Grid.RowDefinitions><RowDefinition Height="auto"/></Grid.RowDefinitions>
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions><ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/></Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
<Rectangle RadiusX="9" RadiusY="9" Fill="White" Stroke="Black" StrokeDashArray="1,2"/>
<TextBlock Padding = "4,2" Text="Whatever"/>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 3):

Our team got this as a requirement lately and we solved it by creating a custom control, `DashedBorder` which extends `Border` and adds the dashed border feature.

It has 3 new dependency properties

- `UseDashedBorder` (bool)
- `DashedBorderBrush` (Brush)
- `StrokeDashArray` (DoubleCollection)

Usable like this

```
<controls:DashedBorder UseDashedBorder="True"
                       DashedBorderBrush="#878787"
                       StrokeDashArray="2 1"
                       Background="#EBEBEB"                               
                       BorderThickness="3"
                       CornerRadius="10 10 10 10">
    <TextBlock Text="Dashed Border"
               Margin="6 2 6 2"/>
</controls:DashedBorder>
```

And produces a result like this
[image]

When `UseDashedBorder` is set to `true` it will create a `VisualBrush` with 2 rectangles and set that as `BorderBrush` (that's why we need an extra property for the color of the actual `BorderBrush`). The first one is to create the dashing and the second of is to fill in the gaps with the `Background` of the border.

It maps the `Rectangle` dashing properties to the `DashedBorder` properties like this

- `StrokeDashArray` => `StrokeDashArray`
- `Stroke` => `DashedBorderBrush`
- `StrokeThickness` => `BorderThickness.Left`
- `RadiusX` => `CornerRadius.TopLeft`
- `RadiusY` => `CornerRadius.TopLeft`
- `Width` => `ActualWidth`
- `Height` => `ActualHeight`

**DashedBorder.cs**

```
public class DashedBorder : Border
{
    private static DoubleCollection? emptyDoubleCollection;
    private static DoubleCollection EmptyDoubleCollection()
    {
        if (emptyDoubleCollection == null)
        {
            DoubleCollection doubleCollection = new DoubleCollection();
            doubleCollection.Freeze();
            emptyDoubleCollection = doubleCollection;
        }
        return emptyDoubleCollection;
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty UseDashedBorderProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(UseDashedBorder),
                                    typeof(bool),
                                    typeof(DashedBorder),
                                    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false, OnUseDashedBorderChanged));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty DashedBorderBrushProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(DashedBorderBrush),
                                    typeof(Brush),
                                    typeof(DashedBorder),
                                    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty StrokeDashArrayProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(StrokeDashArray),
                                    typeof(DoubleCollection),
                                    typeof(DashedBorder),
                                    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(EmptyDoubleCollection()));

    private static void OnUseDashedBorderChanged(DependencyObject target, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        DashedBorder dashedBorder = (DashedBorder)target;
        dashedBorder.UseDashedBorderChanged();
    }

    private Rectangle GetBoundRectangle()
    {
        Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle();

        rectangle.SetBinding(Rectangle.StrokeThicknessProperty, new Binding() { Source = this, Path = new PropertyPath("BorderThickness.Left") });
        rectangle.SetBinding(Rectangle.RadiusXProperty, new Binding() { Source = this, Path = new PropertyPath("CornerRadius.TopLeft") });
        rectangle.SetBinding(Rectangle.RadiusYProperty, new Binding() { Source = this, Path = new PropertyPath("CornerRadius.TopLeft") });
        rectangle.SetBinding(Rectangle.WidthProperty, new Binding() { Source = this, Path = new PropertyPath(ActualWidthProperty) });
        rectangle.SetBinding(Rectangle.HeightProperty, new Binding() { Source = this, Path = new PropertyPath(ActualHeightProperty) });

        return rectangle;
    }

    private Rectangle GetBackgroundRectangle()
    {
        Rectangle rectangle = GetBoundRectangle();
        rectangle.SetBinding(Rectangle.StrokeProperty, new Binding() { Source = this, Path = new PropertyPath(BackgroundProperty) });
        return rectangle;
    }

    private Rectangle GetDashedRectangle()
    {
        Rectangle rectangle = GetBoundRectangle();
        rectangle.SetBinding(Rectangle.StrokeDashArrayProperty, new Binding() { Source = this, Path = new PropertyPath(StrokeDashArrayProperty) });
        rectangle.SetBinding(Rectangle.StrokeProperty, new Binding() { Source = this, Path = new PropertyPath(DashedBorderBrushProperty) });
        Panel.SetZIndex(rectangle, 2);
        return rectangle;
    }

    private VisualBrush CreateDashedBorderBrush()
    {
        VisualBrush dashedBorderBrush = new VisualBrush();
        Grid grid = new Grid();
        Rectangle backgroundRectangle = GetBackgroundRectangle();
        Rectangle dashedRectangle = GetDashedRectangle();
        grid.Children.Add(backgroundRectangle);
        grid.Children.Add(dashedRectangle);
        dashedBorderBrush.Visual = grid;
        return dashedBorderBrush;
    }

    private void UseDashedBorderChanged()
    {
        if (UseDashedBorder)
        {
            BorderBrush = CreateDashedBorderBrush();
        }
        else
        {
            ClearValue(BorderBrushProperty);
        }
    }

    public bool UseDashedBorder
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(UseDashedBorderProperty); }
        set { SetValue(UseDashedBorderProperty, value); }
    }

    public Brush DashedBorderBrush
    {
        get { return (Brush)GetValue(DashedBorderBrushProperty); }
        set { SetValue(DashedBorderBrushProperty, value); }
    }

    public DoubleCollection StrokeDashArray
    {
        get { return (DoubleCollection)GetValue(StrokeDashArrayProperty); }
        set { SetValue(StrokeDashArrayProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

Comment: Symmetry is not guaranteed for dashed-dotted with rounded corners

Answer (score 0):

Working on a user control....
I have been trying a storyboard for a marching ants border.  The basic grid with a rectangle and text works fine since there is no interaction.  When trying to put a button inside the grid, then either the rectangle or button is visible but never both of them.

From another post:
[Advanced XAML Animation effects. Pulse, Marching ants, Rotations. Alerts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25877737/advanced-xaml-animation-effects-pulse-marching-ants-rotations-alerts/25978608)

Using dotNet's solution for the VisualBrush shifted the rectangle to the border with a button inside.  This worked perfectly.

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}" x:Key="LOC_DG_Cell_Mid" BasedOn="{StaticResource DG_TextBlock_Mid}" >
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5 0"/>
        </Style>
        <Storyboard x:Key="MarchingAnts">
            <DoubleAnimation BeginTime="00:00:00"
                Storyboard.TargetName="AlertBox"                                
                Storyboard.TargetProperty="StrokeThickness"
                To="4"
                Duration="0:0:0.25" />
            <!-- If you want to run counter-clockwise, just swap the 'From' and 'To' values. -->
            <DoubleAnimation BeginTime="00:00:00" RepeatBehavior="Forever" Storyboard.TargetName="AlertBox" Storyboard.TargetProperty="StrokeDashOffset" 
                            Duration="0:3:0" From="1000" To="0"/>
        </Storyboard>
    </ResourceDictionary>

</UserControl.Resources>
<UserControl.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.Loaded">
        <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource MarchingAnts}"/>
    </EventTrigger>
</UserControl.Triggers>

<Grid>
    <Border BorderThickness="1">
        <Border.BorderBrush>
            <VisualBrush>
                <VisualBrush.Visual>
                    <Rectangle x:Name="AlertBox" Stroke="Red" StrokeDashOffset="2" StrokeDashArray="5" Margin="5"
                      Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Border}}, Path=ActualWidth}"
                      Height="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Border}}, Path=ActualHeight}"/>
                </VisualBrush.Visual>
            </VisualBrush>
        </Border.BorderBrush>

        <Button x:Name="FinishedButton" Padding="0 5" Margin="0" Style="{StaticResource IconButton}" >
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
                <Label Style="{StaticResource ButtonLabel}" Content="Processing has Finished" />
            </StackPanel>
        </Button>
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for pixel perfect dashed lines

[image: Note that there is no shadow/blur at the end of of each line]

```
public static class DashBrushFactory
    {
        public static Brush CreateBrush(double dpiScale, SolidColorBrush solidColorBrush)
        {
            const double dashLength = 4;
            const double dashSpace = 4;

            double dashLengthPixelSnapped = SnapToPixel(dashLength, dpiScale);
            double dashSpacePixelSnapped = SnapToPixel(dashSpace, dpiScale);

            ImageBrush imageBrush = new ImageBrush();
            DrawingImage drawingImage = new DrawingImage();
            GeometryDrawing geometryDrawing = new GeometryDrawing();
            GeometryGroup geometryGroup = new GeometryGroup();
            RectangleGeometry rectangleGeometry1 = new RectangleGeometry();
            RectangleGeometry rectangleGeometry2 = new RectangleGeometry();

            rectangleGeometry1.Rect = new Rect(0, 0, dashLengthPixelSnapped, dashLengthPixelSnapped);
            rectangleGeometry2.Rect = new Rect(dashLengthPixelSnapped, dashLengthPixelSnapped, dashSpacePixelSnapped, dashSpacePixelSnapped);

            rectangleGeometry1.Freeze();
            rectangleGeometry2.Freeze();

            geometryGroup.Children.Add(rectangleGeometry1);
            geometryGroup.Children.Add(rectangleGeometry2);
            geometryGroup.Freeze();

            geometryDrawing.Brush = solidColorBrush;
            geometryDrawing.Geometry = geometryGroup;
            geometryDrawing.Freeze();

            drawingImage.Drawing = geometryDrawing;
            drawingImage.Freeze();
            imageBrush.TileMode = TileMode.Tile;
            imageBrush.ViewportUnits = BrushMappingMode.Absolute;
            imageBrush.Viewport = new Rect(0, 0, dashLengthPixelSnapped * 2, dashSpacePixelSnapped * 2);
            imageBrush.ImageSource = drawingImage;
            imageBrush.Freeze();

            return imageBrush;
        }

        private static double SnapToPixel(double value, double dpiScale)
        {
            double newValue;

            // If DPI == 1, don't use DPI-aware rounding.
            if (DoubleUtil.AreClose(dpiScale, 1.0) == false)
            {
                newValue = Math.Round(value * dpiScale) / dpiScale;
                // If rounding produces a value unacceptable to layout (NaN, Infinity or MaxValue), use the original value.
                if (DoubleUtil.IsNaN(newValue) ||
                    Double.IsInfinity(newValue) ||
                    DoubleUtil.AreClose(newValue, Double.MaxValue))
                {
                    newValue = value;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                newValue = Math.Round(value);
            }

            return newValue;
        }
    }
```

https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#WindowsBase/Shared/MS/Internal/DoubleUtil.cs