# XAML: rotation around its axis 3d

Tags: wpf, xaml

Is it possible to create animations for two controls like they are on two sides of rectangle. And rectangle is rotating around its axe (3d)?

Something like this:
[image]

Blue side - first control, and the green one - second.

I.e. I want both controls to be shown one by one eternally.

Comment: Yes, there's some methods, and it usually involves some tweaking, but for a quick example you might check out the "Flipper" animation on a previous answer I gave [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25877737/how-to-add-remove-effects-on-ui-elements-from-xaml-creating-pulsing-outerglow) for inspiration to start.