# How to make blinking rectangle stroke in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, storyboard, wpf-controls

Below my rectangle in WPF:

```
<Rectangle Margin="5,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Width="380" Height="25" Fill="LightYellow" Stroke="Orange" StrokeThickness="2" RadiusX="8" RadiusY="8"/>
```

I would like to start bliking for some seconds (and then stop) the rectangle stroke property when a property "StartBlinking" in view model changes from false to true.

I would like to implement storyboard in xaml not in c# code.

How can I do this?

I have tried this but not working:

```
<Rectangle Margin="5,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Width="380" Height="25" Fill="LightYellow" Stroke="Orange" StrokeThickness="2" RadiusX="8" RadiusY="8">

        <Rectangle.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Rectangle}">
                <Style.Resources>
                    <Storyboard x:Key="flashAnimation" >
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Stroke" From="1" To="0" AutoReverse="True" Duration="0:0:0.5" RepeatBehavior="Forever" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </Style.Resources>
            </Style>
        </Rectangle.Style>    
</Rectangle>
```

I am using C# and .NET 3.5 in Visual Studio 2008.

Answer (score 1):

You could animate the `Opacity` property of the `Stroke` using a `DataTrigger` and a `Storyboard`:

```
    <Rectangle Margin="5,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Width="380" Height="25" Fill="LightYellow" 
                   Stroke="Orange" StrokeThickness="2" RadiusX="8" RadiusY="8">
    <Rectangle.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Rectangle">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding StartBlinking}" Value="True">
                    <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Stroke.(SolidColorBrush.Opacity)" 
                                                         To="0" AutoReverse="True" Duration="0:0:0.5" RepeatBehavior="6x" />
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                    <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Stroke.(SolidColorBrush.Opacity)" 
                                                         To="1" Duration="0:0:0.5" />
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Rectangle.Style>
</Rectangle>
```

Comment: I will try it thanks. Also I have found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36457915/how-to-put-a-gradient-on-a-rectangle-stroke-and-animate-it  but seems EasingPointKeyFrame is not supported in .NET 3.5, how can I adapt this to .NET 3.5?

Comment: Why would you need one to make a Rectangle blink...?

Comment: I have tried your solution. When I set StartBlinking property to true from view model it starts to blink but two things:

1) It is blinking the entire rectangle body, not the stroke, I would like only the stroke to blink if possible.
2)  Once start blinking it never stops.

Comment: It stops when you set the StartBlinking property to false provided that you implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface and raise the PropertyChanged event.

Comment: ah ok, sorry, and there is the possibilty it stops automatically after x seconds once it has started? without the need to set the property to false.

Comment: Setting RepeatBehavior="6x" stops it automatically after 6 times.

Comment: And changing the Storyboard.Target property to "Stroke.(SolidColorBrush.Opacity)" animates the Stroke. I edited my answer.

Comment: Great! but now I get an exception saying: Stroke property does not point to a DependencyObject in path 'Stroke.(0)'

Comment: Did you try my sample markup as-is? Try with the following path: Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.Stroke).(SolidColorBrush.Opacity)"

Comment: Yes I have copied exactly the same piece of code you posted. Changing to  Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.Stroke).(SolidColorBru‌​sh.Opacity)" the following error appears: "Stroke property does not point to a DependencyObject in path '(0).(1)' "

Comment: It certainly works for me. By the way, .NET 3.5 is not officially supported any more. You should upgrade. I guess "(Shape.Stroke).(SolidColorBrush.Opacity)" gives the same error?

Comment: Well, then there are some features that are not available for you as well. This seems to be one of them apparently if you can't get it to work based on my sample that works just fine for me.

Comment: Sorry, i have checked (Shape.Stroke).(SolidColorBrush.Opacity) and this does not throws any error but stroke is not blinking

Comment: Also I have tried to do something like this, adapted to the stroke property but without success: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/73dd1434-b0ec-44bb-83cd-039292274f20/error-fill-property-does-not-point-to-a-dependencyobject-in-path-01?forum=wpf