# How to fill Rectangle with lines in UWP

Tags: xaml, uwp, shapes

I am sure I could do better with the title but here is what I am looking for. I have a UWP app where I want to achieve something like this screenshot: [image]

Here is a snippet from my code:

```
<Border BorderBrush="Black">
    <Grid>
        <Rectangle Fill="Green" />
    </Grid>
</Border>
```

I am trying to fill the Rectangle in the Grid with the shapes given in the screenshot. How can I do that?

Comment: When I try to add VisualBrush Resource in the Page.Resources it says 'Cannot resolve symbol 'VisualBrush''

Comment: This is not a duplicate because it's about UWP, not WPF. There is no VisualBrush in UWP.

Comment: If the Rectangle isn't extremely large, you could prepare a BitmapImage resource and use it with an ImageBrush.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, while I don't have a way to test on UWP at the moment, I assume things like `LinearGradientBrush` and `MappingMode` are supported since this way would work on WPF, Silverlight, whatever else... With that assumption, give this a shot.

```
<Rectangle Stroke="LightBlue" StrokeThickness="5">
    <Rectangle.Fill>
        <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="6,4" 
                             MappingMode="Absolute" SpreadMethod="Repeat">
            <GradientStop Color="LightBlue" Offset="0.25"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#00000000" Offset="0.15"/>
        </LinearGradientBrush>
    </Rectangle.Fill>
</Rectangle>
```

[image]

You might tweak your Starts/Ends/Offsets for desired angle and size but it conveys the concept. For example if you increase your `EndPoint` numbers you'll get the thicker lines like in your example.

You can also turn the brush into a resource and use it as a resource for Paths, or Backgrounds, or whatever supports LinearGradientBrush usually. Hope this helps, cheers.

PS - Some [other neat things](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25877737/advanced-xaml-animation-effects-pulse-marching-ants-rotations-alerts) you can do with them that should be easy to port to UWP.

Addendum:

This is closer to your example to save you a little trouble, notice the differences.

```
<Rectangle Stroke="LightBlue" StrokeThickness="5">
    <Rectangle.Fill>
        <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="8,0" EndPoint="18,8" 
                     MappingMode="Absolute" SpreadMethod="Repeat">
            <GradientStop Color="LightBlue" Offset="0.15"/>
            <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0.05"/>
        </LinearGradientBrush>
    </Rectangle.Fill>
</Rectangle>
```

Comment: It works fine. Thanks Chris. I possible I would like to keep the thickness of white lines as it is but increase it for the blue ones.

Comment: @AshishAgrawal Just play around with increasing the numbers on Endpoint like I suggested, right around 20 or so for one of them should do it. But if you tinker with it you'll get exactly what you want and learn something in the process too. ;)

Comment: :) I tried doing that but the thing is as I change the EndPoint to something like {12,6} it also makes the White line thicker (which I don't want). Anyway, thanks a lot for the code, I will try and tweak it to match it exactly with the screenshot. Thanks again :)

Comment: @AshishAgrawal See updated answer, I added another example to bring it to your example or close, notice the differences. :)

Comment: thanks a ton for doing it. I was close but this is perfect :)