# ActualHeight Grows But Doesn't Shrink

Tags: wpf, xaml, datatemplate, itemscontrol

I'm experiencing an odd behavior with WPF.

My goal here is to have an `ItemsControl` with a vertical line on each item's side going from the top to the bottom of the item. Being that the items may vary in height, I'm binding the `Line`'s `Y2` property to the `ActualHeight` of the `StackPanel` belonging to the `Grid`.

Here's the XAML:

```
<ItemsControl Grid.Row="1" BorderThickness="0" ItemsSource="{Binding ShipmentActivity}" >
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Name="ListBox">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="20"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <Line Stroke="{StaticResource ButtonOutlineBrush}" X1="8" X2="8" Y1="0"
                      Y2="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=ShipmentActivity}"
                      StrokeThickness="1" />

                <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Margin=".1" x:Name="ShipmentActivity">
                    <StackPanel.Resources>
                        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                            <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap"/>
                        </Style>
                    </StackPanel.Resources>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Status}" FontWeight="SemiBold" FontSize="13" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Location}" Foreground="Gray"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="Wed, Sep 13, 2017, 8:29 PM (2 days ago)" Foreground="Gray"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Running this at first seems perfect. The problem is noticeable once I start to narrow the width of the window, causing the `TextBlock`s to wrap, and in effect 
causing the items to grow in height, and then resizing the window back to its original width (and beyond). Although the `TextBlock`s are back to its original state (and height), the height of the items remain the same - stuck at its highest point, leaving huge gaps below the text, while the `Line`'s height doesn't shrink. The `Line` is definitely the one to blame here, because removing the line removes the issue.

What is even stranger yet, is adding a margin to the `StackPanel` even the slightest (.1) fixes the issue, and the items shrink back to its intended height.

Am I doing something wrong, or is this a bug?

Comment: Quickie workaround, swap the `Line` with `<Rectangle Fill="{StaticResource ButtonOutlineBrush}" Width="1"/>` which is the best I can offer without time to go load up your example if I don't find time later to investigate it and nobody offers better by then. :)

Comment: Any reason this question was downvoted?

Comment: People do that anonymously all the time and it can be pretty irritating without even an brief explanation. So I can't speak as to why, but since I was apparently subscribed to this post from leaving a comment and saw this I can at least put you back at zero to offset your drive-by downvoter. :)

Comment: @ChrisW. Thanks for your workaround, this actually works, in my current case that can actually be the preferred way, but if I would ever want to have the line dotted, it won't work. Oh, and thanks for the upvote! :-)

Comment: Disregard, I just noticed I can use `Rectangle` and change `Fill` to `Stroke` and then be able set dashes. Thanks!

Comment: Hah true, and ya I started using that trick once on a huge project I had to do once awhile back when it just became too much of a pain to have so my coord bindings inherited all over the place. Either way, cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a **Border** element to decorate the **StackPanel**, rather than using a **Line**. Then just set the `BorderThickness` property of the Border accordingly.

Hence your XAML would be like this:

```
<ItemsControl ...>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Border BorderThickness="1,0,0,0"
                BorderBrush="{StaticResource ButtonOutlineBrush}">
                <StackPanel ...>
```

You can use the `Padding` property of the Border and/or the `Margin` property of the StackPanel to space-out the two elements.

Comment: Thank you. The problem with `Border` is that it doesn't allow dashed lines. But it should be good in my case. Regardless the workaround, is this issue by design or is this a bug?

Comment: @SamWhite You could use a **DrawingBrush** instead of a solid colour brush, as per [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17431518/4265041), but the **Rectangle** approach is probably easier. I'd still use a **Border** element to contain both the rectangle and your text blocks though, rather than trying to bind to the `ActualHeight` property.

Comment: @SamWhite As to why your original approach didn't work, I'm not sure, sorry.